# Maven script shows that Java command is not executable

Tags: bash, shell, maven

After installation on Ubuntu, `mvn -version` prints:

> The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
>   This environment variable is needed to run this program
>   NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

I detected that the problem is in

```
if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
  echo "The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly" >&2
  echo "This environment variable is needed to run this program" >&2
  echo "NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

When I remove quotes from `"$JAVACMD"` it works perfectly

I saw that other scripts use commands with in quotes and I doubt that Maven released this script with errors. So, what seems to be the problem? Why my script won't work in original version? Type of script is `#!/bin/sh` but I tested this condition separately in new file with bash script. The result is the same. When I ask with quotes is command executable, result is false. When I ask without quotes is true

Edit:
I put directly that case in new bash file. The result is interesting

```
#!/bin/bash

JAVACMD1="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
JAVACMD2="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java"

echo $JAVACMD1
echo $JAVACMD2


if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD1" ]
then
    echo "NOT"
else
    echo "YES"
fi

if [ ! -x $JAVACMD1 ]
then
    echo "NOT"
else
    echo "YES"
fi

if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD2" ]
then
    echo "NOT"
else
    echo "YES"
fi
```

Result:

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
>   NOT
>   YES
>   YES

Comment: How have you installed Maven? Downloaded from original page https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi ?

Comment: How have you set JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: Installed by sudo app install maven and JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 but it seems that the problem is not in that. My question is general about this condition in shell script

Comment: Is a directory `bin` within `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64` which contains `java`?

Comment: Yes. I also echoed a variable $JAVACMD and prints /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java. And java -version works ok. And when I run the command in the script it shows the same thing. When I put "$JAVACMD" it only prints /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java but when I remove the quotes it executes the java command. It is not related to the Maven. It is something with that java file

Comment: Is this `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java` really the location or is this just a link? Also I recommend to download OpenJDK (AdoptOpenJDK) and install it via `tar.gz` and retry it...with JAVA_HOME set to the installation...

Comment: It is a link. But that is regular in JDK, I think. I tested some code with link and without the link. The result is always the same

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in env variable `JAVA_HOME`. It started with one blank, but that I didn't see in `echo` command (I suppose it trims the string). In command prompt I also used `echo`, but when I listed all env variables I saw it